# Unable to return an interface in mocked method when it should be a internal sealed class

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit.net

We are creating unit tests in XUnit for one of our projects our ASP.NET application. In the project, we are trying to mock out a particular third party client we don't have access to the source code and does not provide an interface (just a client object we can create). To fix this, we wrote a wrapper class and an interface to that class so we can mock out the functionality we need for that client. This part is all good.

One of the methods we created in the wrapper class and interface was a GetInnerChannel method to get a property from the client (which we want to mock out). However, that method returns an Interface of IClientChannel from System.ServiceModel.

```
public IClientChannel GetInnerChannel()
{
        return client.InnerChannel;
}
```

It seems harmless, but, in our mock setup, we are unable to create a fake IClientChannel object that is useful for the method we are testing. Here is our unit test code for clarification:

```
client.Setup(i => i.GetInnerChannel()).Returns(GetClientChannel());
```

In the Returns call, you will see we are returning a method return which we currently set to null for now. This is because we cannot instantiate an interface. When I dived into debugging, I found that the object that is being sent back in place of the interface during normal operation is a System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.__TransparentProxy object. A little investigation into the __TransparentProxy class is that it is an internal sealed class (which means we cannot instantiate that in our unit test code).

Unfortunately, the method we are testing is using the InnerChannel in this way:

```
public List<EquifaxQuestion> GetEquifaxQuestions(User basicUserInfo, IEnumerable<AddressViewModel> Addresses)
    {
        try
        {
            InitialResponse response;
            using (new OperationContextScope(client.GetInnerChannel()))
            {
                OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(
                    new EquifaxSecurityHeader(appID, username, password));

                response = client.SubmitInitialInteraction(GenerateInitialRequest(basicUserInfo, Addresses));
            }
```

Which I don't if we can replace the GetInnerChannel call and thus we require a mock of it to just get through the unit test since we must mock out our client.

Is there another way I can return a value or object that is useful for GetInnerChannel()? Am I missing a step in my mock setups? Or is Moq and other mocking frameworks incapable to do what I need to do? Or is the method I am trying unit test against unable to be unit tested? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why can't you mock `IClientChannel`? something like `var clientChannelMock = new Mock<IClientChannel>(); client.Setup(i => i.GetInnerChannel()).Returns(clientChannelMock);`

Comment: I tried that. The problem is in the methods we are testing, we are have the following line:

`using (new OperationContextScope(client.GetInnerChannel())){
                    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(
                        new EquifaxSecurityHeader(appID, username, password));`

The problem is that OperationContextScope throws the error `Invalid IContextChannel passed to OperationContext. Must be either a server dispatching channel or a client proxy channel.` Also, we are then using a static method to set up the headers (which can't be mocked).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the solution for this was a lot of wrappers and interfaces to work in WCF. It is quite lengthy, but this blog post does a better job. https://weblogs.asp.net/cibrax/unit-tests-for-wcf

In short, if you have static, sealed, or other third party class you can't mock, wrap it in a simple task with all public methods written in them with them calling your third party class's method and then create an interface for the wrapper. In your unit tests, use the interface and in your normal code, use your wrapper class.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible without having to write any more wrappers. It is important to understand the principle of indirection that gets introduced by adding an interface. Every interface added is an opportunity to isolate the abstraction and make it look and feel different.

I have attached the important snippets below, due to expected brevity I am not attaching entire solution.

Quick explaination of classes and usage hierarchy -
1. IInnerChannel is the interface exposed by the third party library.
2. IClientChannelWrapper is the wrapper class created in order to hide inner interface from calling clients.
3. ClassUsingChannelWrapper is the class that invokes this logic and in our unit test its method is going to be our sut (subject under test).

Code goes as below -

The IInnerChannel interface declaration-

```
public interface IInnerChannel
{
    string TheInnerChannelMethod();
}
```

The InnerChannel implementation (probably in the third party library in your case)-

```
public class InnerChannelImplementation : IInnerChannel
{
    public InnerChannelImplementation()
    {
    }

    public string TheInnerChannelMethod()
    {
        var result = "This is coming from innser channel.";
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        return result;

    }
}
```

The wrapper created by you around the inner channel -

```
public interface IClientChannelWrapper
{
    void DoSomething();
    IInnerChannel GetTheInnerChannelMethod();
}
```

The wrapper interface's implementation -

```
public class ClientChannelWrapperImplementation : IClientChannelWrapper
{
    public ClientChannelWrapperImplementation()
    {
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The DoSomething Method!");
    }

    public IInnerChannel GetTheInnerChannelMethod()
    {
        InnerChannelImplementation imp = new InnerChannelImplementation();
        return imp;
    }
}
```

The class that calls your wrapper's implementation. This class is going to be your SUT when implementing unit tests -

```
public class ClassUsingChannelWrapper
{
    IClientChannelWrapper _wrapper;
    public ClassUsingChannelWrapper(IClientChannelWrapper wrapper)
    {
        _wrapper = wrapper;
    }

    public void TheClientChannelConsumerMethod()
    {
        IInnerChannel theChannel = _wrapper.GetTheInnerChannelMethod();
        var result = theChannel.TheInnerChannelMethod();
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Finally, the unit test with mocks mimicking behaviour of both interfaces. Notice how mocked client channel wrapper is returning mocked internal channel object which returns pre-programmed value.

```
public class UnitTest1
{
    [Fact]
    public void Test1()
    {
        //Arrange
        Mock<IInnerChannel> innerChannelMock = new Mock<IInnerChannel>();
        innerChannelMock.Setup(i => i.TheInnerChannelMethod()).Returns("This 
        is a test from mocked object.");
        Mock<InterfaceUt.IClientChannelWrapper> mockClientWrapper = new 
        Mock<IClientChannelWrapper>();
        mockClientWrapper.Setup(m => 
        m.GetTheInnerChannelMethod()).Returns(innerChannelMock.Object);

        //Act
        ClassUsingChannelWrapper sut = new 
        ClassUsingChannelWrapper(mockClientWrapper.Object);
        sut.TheClientChannelConsumerMethod();

        //Assert
        innerChannelMock.Verify();
        mockClientWrapper.Verify();

    }
}
```

Running this unit test prints

"This is a test from mocked object."

Essentially, your unit test is targeting only the client code that attempts to use your interface behaviour. This does not test the implementation of your wrapper. If you want to achieve that you will have to create a new instance of wrapper class instead of mock object and feed it with inner channel's mock object.